# ciclo FOR triple, para llenar datos de un arreglo. c++

Tags: c++

Tengo un problema, quiero hacer un ciclo FOR triple, para poder llenar datos.

Trabajadores(OK).

Horas trabajadas del día(OK).

Salario(X).

lo que quiero hacer es que en el primero ciclo FOR, se muestren los trabajadores eso está OK no me da problema. Luego se vayan guardando las horas de cada día trabajado, del lunes hasta el viernes, eso esta OKAY. pero el tercer ciclo me da un problema, no se como hacer para guardar el sueldo en ese mismo ciclo para cada trabajador de forma independiente. Tengo mi código que es el siguiente, espero alguien me pueda ayudar, a poder completar ese ciclo, se que puedo hacer otro ciclo para guardar exactamente el salario sin problema pero me gustaría hacerlo desde ahí. Saludos a toda la comunidad.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {

    string a[5]={"Juan","Pedro","Luis","Goku","Chabelo"};
    string diaz[6]={"lunes","martes","miercoles","jueves","viernes","sabado"};
    int h=0;
    int ht[5];
    int total=0;
    int sueldo[5];
    int salary=0;


    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        cout<<"Trabajador: "<<a[i]<<endl;
        for(int j=0; j<6; j++){
            cout<<"Horas trabajadas el día "<<diaz[j]<<endl;
            cin>>h;
            total=total+h;
            ht[i]=total;
        }
        for(int q=0; q<5; q++){
            cout<<"Sueldo del trabajador"<<endl;
            cin>>salary;
            sueldo[q]=salary;
        }
    total=0;
        salary=0;

    }

    cout<<"Horas trabajadas: "<<endl;
    for(int x=0; x<3; x++) {
     cout<<a[x] <<" ["<<ht[x]<<" Horas]"<<endl;
        }
    cout<<"Sueldo semanal: "<<endl;
    for(int k=0; k<3; k++) {
        cout<<a[k]<<"["<<sueldo[k]<<"]"<<endl;
    }




    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto es más una confusión de diseño que de lenguaje. No necesitas iterar **otra vez** sobre todos los trabajadores para definir el sueldo, ya que vas trabajador por trabajador... El mismo bucle que utilizas para recorrer los trabajadores te sirve para asignar el sueldo de cada uno.

Ya que `i` representa cada trabajador en el ciclo externo, entonces `sueldo[i]` representa el sueldo de cada trabajador, no hace falta otro `for` para asignar este valor.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  cout << "Trabajador: " << a[i] << endl;
  for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
    cout << "Horas trabajadas el día " << diaz[j] << endl;
    cin >> h;
    total = total + h;
    ht[i] = total;
  }

  //INICIO DE CORRECION
  cout << "Sueldo del trabajador" << endl;
  cin >> salary;
  sueldo[i] = salary;
  //FIN DE CORRECION

  total = 0;
  salary = 0;
}
```

Espero que esto te ayude, suerte programando!

Comment: Gracias por compartir tu conocimiento amigo, pasa buen día